# Carousel with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm just getting into angularJS and already love it. I've written a website locally that will allow me pull data from JSON files(created automatically with external scripts) to display data in realtime on different pages. I'd like to create a sliding carousel that will display this info that I'm pulling in with angularJS.

Unfortunately all of the carousel templates I've seen consist of just accessing stored images. Is there a way to use a carousel slider to display data versus just an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had great success with the jQuery plugin [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

[Here is a demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php) of, I think, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks like it could be exactly what I need! Thanks! I'll set  that answer as soon as it'll let me =)

Comment: No prob. cycle2 is highly customizable and can hit almost any scenario. And they have good documentation. Keep it in your tool belt ;)